# No bean named 'notificationsDependencyFactory' is defined

Tags: java, junit4, spring-test, spring-java-config

I need to write an integration test, which involves some Spring xml configuration files already existent (and working), to which I have to add a single new bean.

Therefore, I am trying to mix the xml-based configuration to a specific Java configuration. Here my try:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AgentSubscriptionServiceTest.AgentSubscriptionServiceTestConfiguration.class)
public class AgentSubscriptionServiceTest
{

  @Resource(name = "agentSubscriptionService")
  private AgentSubscriptionService service;

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception
  {
    service.register(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  @Configuration
  @ImportResource({
    "classpath:/database-tx-context.xml",
    "classpath:/logic-tx-context.xml",
    "classpath:/test-logic-repo-context.xml"
  })
  public static class AgentSubscriptionServiceTestConfiguration {

    public AgentSubscriptionServiceTestConfiguration() {}

    @Bean(name = "agentSubscriptionService")
    public AgentSubscriptionService getAgentSubscriptionService() {
      return new AgentSubscriptionService();
    }

  }
}
```

This code however raised an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:307)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springCacheNotificationTransportFactory': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'notificationsDependencyFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'notificationsDependencyFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:444)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:418)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 41 more
```

I cannot find any reference to the missing bean (`notificationsDependencyFactory`).

I can guarantee the referenced xmls are fine, in fact if I try to use only the mentioned xml I only get a `No bean named 'agentSubscriptionService' is defined` (which is obviously correct since that one is exactly the bean I am trying to define in my test).

Any idea? This time Google is not helping me!

**EDIT: workaround**. Using pure xml configuration, the problem does not arise.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:/database-tx-context.xml",
    "classpath:/logic-tx-context.xml",
    "classpath:/test-logic-repo-context.xml",
    "classpath:/agent-subscriptions-context.xml"
    })
public class AgentSubscriptionServiceTest
{

  @Resource(name = "agentSubscriptionService")
  private AgentSubscriptionService service;

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception
  {
    service.register(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }
}
```

In `agent-subscriptions-context.xml` I describe a single bean, `<bean id="agentSubscriptionService" class="package.AgentSubscriptionService" />`. I do not like this solution since the new xml is specific for a single test and I would rather have it coupled with the test (inner class is in fact my thought) but I do not understand what is and why Spring needs `notificationsDependencyFactory` only when mixing xml with Java config. Still looking for the inner class solution.

Comment: The `springCacheNotificationTransportFactory` needs a bean name `notificationsDependencyFactory`, which is not defined.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got busy in other tasks. I understand the problem, I do not know what can cause it and why I have the problem only when I mix java and xml configuration. In fact (see question update) using pure xml configuration it works fine.

Comment: This may _potentially_ be a bug in core Spring; however, without access to your project, we can't really help you debug it. So please [create a JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) (against the "Spring Framework" project and "Test" component) and submit a simplified [issue project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues#readme) that reproduces the behavior you are witnessing.